# Data auto commit issue when Connection lost contract issue occurs in Oracle 12C

Tags: oracle11g

I am using bulk insert option for inserting high volume data. While insertion is in process am getting error like **Connection lost contract**. After i get this error, Already inserted data not getting rollback.

All my logic written in a procedure and in Exception block **when others** am doing Rollback. But rollback is not happening.

Please suggest me , Is it the default behavior of Oracle Or Is there any other way to rollback data when **Connection lost contract** error occurs in between the process.

Comment: I am not certain that I understand the question.  If you are getting a connection related error, that error is presumably not coming from a PL/SQL block unless that PL/SQL block has some sort of connection to an external system (a database link, a web service call, etc.).  It sounds like the error you're getting is coming from the client application (an actual error stack would be useful).

Comment: If the client asks the database to execute a stored procedure and loses the connection before the procedure completes, the database will finish running the procedure before trying to send the response to the client and discovering that the connection is lost.  If the procedure commits, then the changes will be committed before the database becomes aware that the client application has lost their connection.